# External Seagate does not working anymore

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

A Seagate (500 GB) hard drive was working very well some days ago, I went to my friend and tried to transfer a 23-gigabyte game but while the transformation process the first 200-300 MB went well then the hard drive started to self disconnected-reconnected and the operation failed so I re-sent the files and it continued self disconnected-reconnected every about 100 MB with very low transfer rate (about 1-2 MB/s), that happened for 5 times of trying then it never got recognized any more!

When I got home I re-tried to plug it with another USB cable and it took longtime till windows recognizes it and when I try to open the hard partitions that get opened but I can't copy from or paste on anything at all (it shows transfer dialog box with rate 200-50 KB/s then decreases to 0 KB/s).

That was all using Windows 8 on a NTFS partition,`status-1:` I tried to re-format it to NTFS but that finished with unsuccessful operation and partition got raw.However, re-formatting it to FAT32 got successful but as mentioned before can't copy from or paste on due to very low transfer rate which gets to be zero!

I've also tried to wipe the NTFS partiton with 0's and 1's, the operation goes success but return to `status-1` and a pop-up balloon after each formatting operation tells USB device not recognized or sometime in spite of telling operations success it returns to unallocated partition.

I've just tried to wipe the whole disk drive with 0's and 1's but the same situation still there.

Is there anyway to let the hard drive gets survived or now it is considered dead physically?

`PS-1`: Hard drive was partitioned as following >> 100 GB NTFS & 400 ext4 (Linux partition)

`PS-2`: all operations done with MiniTool partition wizard.

`PS-3`: when I try to do a surface test Minitool program gets closed immediately.

**UPDATE:**

I tried the below described process of using *diskpart* tool but after 9 hours of formatting very slowly it showed the following:
[image: Command Window screenshot]

Then a popped-up message shown:

[image: Popup screenshot]

And every time I re-connect the hard, Windows asks me to format it before use then end with "Windows unable to format the disk"!

Also, in MiniTool partition wizard `used space` shown as all used and 0 `unused`.

Comment: It may just be the USB controller of the drive that's failing, especially if you don't hear any strange noise that would suggest a mechanical failure. An external HDD is often just a standard internal hard disk and a small SATA<->USB converter, so you can always disassemble the external HDD enclosure and put the drive in your PC to see if it works fine without that converter.

Answer (score 1):

Your disk is probably in its agony. Anyway, you can try to clean the partition table, and setup it again. I you don't have any data on it (you should have a backup!) you can clean the disk with *diskpart* tool. This is build-in Microsoft partition editor. Do as follows:

1. Connect your disk to PC an wait until it is recognized by Windows.
2. Start Administrator command line. Type *cmd* in Start Menu, right click on Command Line icon and choose Run As Administrator.
3. Run the *diskpart* program:

   `C:\diskpart`
4. Display the available disks:

   `DISKPART>list disk`
5. You will see list of all available disk drives. Let's say that yours is the one with number 2, select it:

   `DISKPART>select disk 2`
6. Now clean first and last megabytes of selected disk:

   `DISKPART>clean`
7. Create new partition, just for test, and format it as NTFS:

   `DISKPART> create partition primary`

   `DISKPART> format fs=ntfs quick label="Look alive!"`
8. Exit diskpart:

   `DISKPART>exit`

If you don't see the NTFS partition with "Look alive!" label or cannot write and read it, then your disk is dead.

Comment: I will try it a bit later, but the question that arises about backup if it is an external hard drive which supposed to be the backups saver ! then where can someone keep his/her data highly safe ?

Comment: Hard drives fail from time to time. It is not that external hard drive is more reliable than internal one, it can fail as well. That is why we should keep our files in several copies on different storage media.

Comment: when I tried these steps above with `quick` from format step it says `DiskPart encountered an error...` so I remove this word and since that it is working on, it is now 11% since an hour it is so slow but I hope that works :)

Comment: Don't worry, it can take a lot of time, hours is nothing strange here. Format without option "quick" checks disk for bad sectors and if found any, marks them as unusable. Option "quick" disables this check and reduces operation time to few seconds.

Comment: I've updated the post, you can check the result... does that confirm that my hard is totally dead ?

Comment: Yes, your disk seems to be dead :-(. It has electronic malfunction or number of bad sectors beyond the disk can handle. But anyway, good thing is that you learned how to check faulty disk :-).